# Fixed element's translate x is out of sync when zoomed on mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fixed header. I have it set to position: fixed, but it can be scrolled along the x-axis. This is the javascript I am using for the x-scroll:

```
var thead = document.querySelector("#acctInqFormResults table tr:first-child");
window.onscroll = function() {
    thead.style["-webkit-transform"] = "translateX(" + -window.scrollX + "px)";
    thead.style.transform = "translateX(" + -window.scrollX + "px)";
};
```

This was working great up until I tested it on mobile devices. When I pinch to zoom in on the table, the fixed heading appears to scroll at the same speed as when the document was loaded at full size thus putting the header and the table contents out of sync. Is there a way I can compensate for mobile zooming?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that adding this viewport meta tag should help mobile browser to calculate position correctly. After all - if you are making mobile-specific site version, zoom is useless and even avoidable altogether for best user experience.

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
```